# Unable to send a good querystring with python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to make a right get request to this url with python and requests library applying some filters:

https://www.efast.dol.gov/5500search/

I just need some filters for get right data inside the search page which are: planyear, ein and pn. When I try to do the request I get the wrong data because my dict gets a deleted value following the "q"

This is a example:

```
import requests

args = {'q.parser': 'lucene', 'q': {'ein': '814699012', 'planyear': '2020', 'pn': '001'}}
url = "https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs"
response = requests.get(url, params=args)
```

When I check response.url I get:

```
https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs?q.parser=lucene&q=ein&q=planyear&q=pn
```

Every key has no value

This is the closest I've been:

```
 args = {"q.parser":"lucene","q":{"ein":"814699012"}, "planyear":"2020","pn":"001"}
```

But if I do response.url I get:

```
'https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs?q.parser=lucene&q=ein&planyear=2020&pn=001
```

The ein value is gone, it doesn't matter if I put planyear or pn as a value next to q, the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

The right result would be data corresponding to year 2020, the right ein number and pn number, It doesn't matter if I get several results or just one

A right result would be this:

```
https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs?q.parser=lucene&size=200&sort=planname%20asc&q=(((planyear:2020))%20AND%20((ein:814699012))%20AND%20((pn:001)))&facet.planyear=%7Bsize:30%7D%26facet.plancode=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.plancode=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.assetseoy=%7Bbuckets:%5B%22%7B,100000%5D%22,%22%5B100001,500000%5D%22,%22%5B500001,1000000%5D%22,%22%5B1000001,10000000%5D%22,%22%5B10000001,%7D%22%5D%7D&facet.plantype=%7Bsize:20%7D&facet.businesscodecat=%7Bsize:30%7D&facet.businesscode=%7Bsize:30%7D&facet.state=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.countrycode=%7Bbuckets:%5B%22CA%22,%22GB%22,%22BM%22,%22KY%22%5D%7D&facet.formyear=%7Bsize:30%7D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's `requests` package doesn't support dict like parameters. They values in key-value dictionary have to be either strings or list of strings:

> Requests allows you to provide these arguments as a dictionary of strings, using the params keyword argument.

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Your website is using non-standard encoding to encode dictionary to url-valid characters.

If you take a look at your example:

```
(((planyear:2020))%20AND%20((ein:814699012))%20AND%20((pn:001)))
```

We can deduce format to:

```
(((KEY:VALUE)) AND ((KEY:VALUE)) AND <...>)
```

So it's `()` where every key:value pair is surrounded with `(())` and  spaces being urlquoted to `%20`.

We can replicate this encoding ourselves in our code:

```py
>>> params = {"planyear": "2020", "ein": 814699012, "pn": "001"}
>>> encoded = '%20AND%20'.join(f"(({k}:{v})" for k, v in params.items())
>>> f"({encoded})"
'(((planyear:2020))%20AND%20((ein:814699012))%20AND%20((pn:001)))'
```

Then just pass this as your `q` parameter.

Edit: I've compiled this for your specific case:

```py
import requests

q = {'ein': '814699012', 'planyear': '2020', 'pn': '001'}
# convert Q parameter to website's encoding: 
q = ' AND '.join(f"(({k}:{v}))" for k, v in q.items())
q = f"({q})"
# put all params together: normal key:value parameters + special Q parameter: 
params = {'q.parser': 'lucene', 'size': 200, 'sort': 'planname asc', 'q': q}
url = "https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs"
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(response.status)
print(response.url)
# 200
# 'https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs?q.parser=lucene&size=200&sort=planname+asc&q=%28%28%28ein%3A814699012%29%29+AND+%28%28planyear%3A2020%29%29+AND+%28%28pn%3A001%29%29%29'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you tested this? I'm trying and no getting the expected result, maybe I'm not understanding what you mean by "just pass this as your q parameter"

Comment: I marked your answer as correcto for your explanation and that guided me to closer solution. I couldn't directly make this work but you helpep me a lot. Thank you

Comment: @MrSam I've clarified my answer with explicit example. See my edit - seems to be working :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are confused about requests and responses.
In your case, you should use the long URL as your requests, and then parse the response JSON data. So the following code should work for you, and you need to parse the response:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs?q.parser=lucene&size=200&sort=planname%20asc&q=(((planyear:2020))%20AND%20((ein:814699012))%20AND%20((pn:001)))&facet.planyear=%7Bsize:30%7D%26facet.plancode=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.plancode=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.assetseoy=%7Bbuckets:%5B%22%7B,100000%5D%22,%22%5B100001,500000%5D%22,%22%5B500001,1000000%5D%22,%22%5B1000001,10000000%5D%22,%22%5B10000001,%7D%22%5D%7D&facet.plantype=%7Bsize:20%7D&facet.businesscodecat=%7Bsize:30%7D&facet.businesscode=%7Bsize:30%7D&facet.state=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.countrycode=%7Bbuckets:%5B%22CA%22,%22GB%22,%22BM%22,%22KY%22%5D%7D&facet.formyear=%7Bsize:30%7D"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Check it out:

```
import requests

parser='lucene'
query='(((planyear:2020))%20AND%20((ein:814699012))%20AND%20((pn:001)))'

url = "https://www.efast.dol.gov/services/afs?q.parser=" + parser + "&size=200&sort=planname%20asc&q=" + query + "&facet.planyear=%7Bsize:30%7D%26facet.plancode=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.plancode=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.assetseoy=%7Bbuckets:%5B%22%7B,100000%5D%22,%22%5B100001,500000%5D%22,%22%5B500001,1000000%5D%22,%22%5B1000001,10000000%5D%22,%22%5B10000001,%7D%22%5D%7D&facet.plantype=%7Bsize:20%7D&facet.businesscodecat=%7Bsize:30%7D&facet.businesscode=%7Bsize:30%7D&facet.state=%7Bsize:100%7D&facet.countrycode=%7Bbuckets:%5B%22CA%22,%22GB%22,%22BM%22,%22KY%22%5D%7D&facet.formyear=%7Bsize:30%7D"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: I want to automate searching some forms, that's the real reason I'm trying to search like this.

Comment: And remember that I mentioned I need to search with 3 parameters like planyear, ein and pn, if need any other specific data and I use this long version I'll need to go to the browser again and that's not the point.

Comment: Check the edited version, is that what you mean? You need to follow the request format from the website instead of guessing, that's my point